# Only show posts with image and the correct ammount of posts in loop

Tags: posts, images, loop

This script makes a loop showing only posts with images, but I have a problem. It doesnt show the right ammount of posts pr page. Probably because it counts the total nr of posts, including the ones without pictures. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
<?php 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $searchimages = '~<img [^>]* />~';
    preg_match_all( $searchimages, $content, $pics );
    $iNumberOfPics = count($pics[0]);
    if ( $iNumberOfPics > 0 ) {
        //your loop content goes here
    } 
endwhile; 
?>
```

Second problem: It also shows broken-image if the image in the post is external.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way is to query the database with LIKE statement and get all IDs and then create a separate WP_Query object for the list of post ID's. Check [this guide](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_query-with-regex-is-it-possible-custom-fields-better?replies=21#post-1462442) for example.

Comment: I'm sorry Mario but my knowlage is not there yet :( can you help?

Comment: it's a bit of manual work, I'm personally using the Views WP plugin that does a lot of querying and has pagination parameters